# How to boot directly into USB Live (Linux Mint)?

Tags: linux, grub, live-usb

I've been trying to let Grub automatically boot into Linux Mint Live ( Using rufus with persistence ) but even though I've tried to edit isolinux.cfg (in USB folder) but it's still does not boot directly into Linux Mint Live unless I manually select it myself. Here's my ioslinux.cfg

```
default live
timeout 5

menu background splash.png
menu title Welcome to Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon 64-bit

menu color screen   37;40      #80ffffff #00000000 std
MENU COLOR border       30;44   #40ffffff #a0000000 std
MENU COLOR title        1;36;44 #ffffffff #a0000000 std
MENU COLOR sel          7;37;40 #e0ffffff #20ffffff all
MENU COLOR unsel        37;44   #50ffffff #a0000000 std
MENU COLOR help         37;40   #c0ffffff #a0000000 std
MENU COLOR timeout_msg  37;40   #80ffffff #00000000 std
MENU COLOR timeout      1;37;40 #c0ffffff #00000000 std
MENU COLOR msg07        37;40   #90ffffff #a0000000 std
MENU COLOR tabmsg       31;40   #ffDEDEDE #00000000 std
MENU WIDTH 78
MENU MARGIN 15
MENU ROWS 7
MENU VSHIFT 10
MENU TABMSGROW 12
MENU CMDLINEROW 12
MENU HELPMSGROW 16
MENU HELPMSGENDROW 29

label live
  menu label Start Linux Mint
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  persistent file=/cdrom/preseed/linuxmint.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --
menu default
label xforcevesa
  menu label Start in compatibility mode
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  persistent file=/cdrom/preseed/linuxmint.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz noapic noacpi nosplash irqpoll nomodeset --
label oem
  menu label OEM install (for manufacturers)
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  persistent file=/cdrom/preseed/linuxmint.seed oem-config/enable=true only-ubiquity boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --
label check
  menu label Integrity check
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  boot=casper integrity-check initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --
label hdt
  menu label Hardware Detection
  kernel hdt.c32
label local
  menu label Boot from local drive
  COM32 chain.c32
  APPEND hd0
label memtest
  menu label Memory test
  kernel /casper/memtest
```

Thanks you and I apologize for my lack of knowledge on this

Comment: Wait, who is "it" in "it doesn't let me"?

Comment: Refer to config file (isolinux.cfg) , even after the edited the grub menu still need to manually select in order to boot in Live Linux ( I've followed a guide on which he said he just change the default value  to the label I want to automatically boot into which is label live )

Comment: So, how does isolinux configuration help us help you configure GRUB?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/32484/how-to-boot-from-ubuntu-live-usb-with-try-ubuntu-directly 
is the link of what I've done with the config

Comment: It's absolutely not arising from the question you've linked to what you did. Anyway, again, what does this have to do with your GRUB? Your GRUB seems to be the thing not doing what you want, and you configure other things than GRUB.